# Quotient group of free groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, normal-subgroups, finitely-generated

Let $G=\langle g_1,\ldots,g_k\rangle$ be a free abelian group generated with $g_1,\ldots,g_k$ and let $H=\langle g_{r+1},\ldots,g_k\rangle$ be a free abelian subgroup of $G$.

Is it then the case that $G/H\simeq\langle g_1,\ldots,g_r\rangle$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map $f:G \to G$ given by
\begin{align*}
f(g_i) &=
\begin{cases}
g_i & \text{if}\;\; i \leq r; \\
0 & \text{if}\;\; i > r
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
has kernel $\langle{g_{r+1}, \dots, g_k\rangle} = H$ (since $G$ is free). Hence $G/H = f(G) = \langle g_1, \dots, g_r\rangle\subset G$.